# Laravel session cache on server (configuration bug)

Tags: laravel, session, devops

I had this weird problem with Sessions in Laravel and couldn't find the solution anywhere. I finally figured it out and I thought that I would share, hoping that it may help someone in the future.

---

## TLDR;

**Problem**: Engintron configuration micro-caching mixing up session IDs

**Solution**: Change session cookie name from `laravel_session` to `userID`

---

## Full Story:

**Problem**: The problem was only really noticeable for me with the login process as this is where the sessions were the most important. I noticed that if two users logged in at the same time or nearly the same time, then they would switch identities or the latter would take the identity as the earlier user. I also noticed that the latter would take the session cookie of the former when logged in as that user.

**Configuration**: Laravel 6.2, PHP 7.2, and Engintron to integrate NGINX to cPanel/WHM

**Reason**: What was happening here was that the sessions were being cached and the latter user was taking the cached version to log in.

Comment: This is a critical bug sessions should not be cached at all.

Comment: Yep, you're absolutely right @Viney . I had trouble with this for a while and, unfortunately, found little documentation online. Hopefully this helps someone else and saves them loads of time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Detailed reason**:

Here is part of the default [configuration](https://github.com/engintron/engintron/blob/master/nginx/proxy_params_dynamic) of Engintron's proxy params dynamic.

```
# CMS (& CMS extension) specific cookies (e.g. Joomla, K2 for Joomla, WordPress, WooCommerce, PrestaShop etc.)
if ($http_cookie ~* "(joomla_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|userID|wordpress_(?!test_)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|wp-postpass|comment_author_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|woocommerce_cart_hash|woocommerce_items_in_cart|wp_woocommerce_session_[a-zA-Z0-9]+|sid_customer_|sid_admin_|PrestaShop-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)") {
    set $CACHE_BYPASS_FOR_DYNAMIC 1;
    set $EXPIRES_FOR_DYNAMIC 0;
}
```

What is going on here is that Engintron will microcache any cookie that is not like:

```
joomla_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|userID|wordpress_(?!test_)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|wp-postpass|comment_author_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|woocommerce_cart_hash|woocommerce_items_in_cart|wp_woocommerce_session_[a-zA-Z0-9]+|sid_customer_|sid_admin_|PrestaShop-[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

Notice that `laravel_session` is nowhere in there. Therefore, Engintron will microcache any laravel session Cookie and, under these configurations, you could be allowing a user to wrongfully login to another account.

## Solution:

There are two ways to solve this. You could adjust the configurations on your server or within your app.

A) Within Laravel:

Change config/session.php line 127 from:

```
'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),
```

to

```
'cookie' => 'userID',
```

B) On the server:

Or simply add `laravel_session` or whatever you are naming your app's cookies within the list of specific cookies like so:

```
if ($http_cookie ~* "(laravel_session|joomla_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|userID|wordpress_(?!test_)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|wp-postpass|comment_author_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|woocommerce_cart_hash|woocommerce_items_in_cart|wp_woocommerce_session_[a-zA-Z0-9]+|sid_customer_|sid_admin_|PrestaShop-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)") {
    set $CACHE_BYPASS_FOR_DYNAMIC 1;
    set $EXPIRES_FOR_DYNAMIC 0;
}
```

I hope this helps someone :)

Happy coding!

Comment: I have also notified Engintron of this issue as well: https://github.com/engintron/engintron/issues/1150

Comment: Thanks, the solution A works! But...can you explain me why you set the key 'cookie' as 'userID' I was looking for information about it but I didn't get anything. Thanks again,

Comment: Laravel used same cookie for guest and logged in users, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: @Zione01, see the two solutions that I have set above.

Comment: @Benyi, this is actually a catchall strategy for different frameworks / CMSs. I.e., you have Joomla, wordpress, etc. in there as well. So, this should work for most people having this problem using Engintron